# Why i am getting Unsupported class file error while running react-native on android device?

Tags: react-native, android-studio

Android Studio SDK Version:- 29.0.2
While Running **npx react-native run-android** command got error

```
startup failed:
```

General error during semantic analysis: Unsupported class file major version 60

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 60

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w68ee.png)

build.gradle file description -

```
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2"
    minSdkVersion = 21
    compileSdkVersion = 30
    targetSdkVersion = 30
    ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It supports `Java 16 from grade 7.0`. However, the gradle version supported by the latest version `android gradle plugin (4.2.0) is 6.7.1` as of now.

Lowering the JDK version to `16` can solve the problem.